# wrapped verses in memoir are not numbered at line start

Tags: memoir, verse

I am using the memoir package to typeset material that includes some psalms. The psalms are placed in the verse environment. I would like the verses to be numbered. But when a verse is particularly long, the wrapping seems to mess up the verse numbers. For example, the code at the bottom of my post produces verses that look like this:

```
   O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger, neither chas-
1       ten me in Thy wrath.
   Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; O Lord,
2       heal me, for my bones are vexed.
```

instead of

```
1   O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger, neither chas-
       ten me in Thy wrath.
2   Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; O Lord,
       heal me, for my bones are vexed.
```

The corresponding code is:

```
%! program = pdflatex
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
    
    \linenumberfrequency{1}
    \verselinenumbersleft   
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{My soul also is sore troubled;}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]      
        O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger, neither chasten me in Thy wrath.\\
        Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; O Lord, heal me, for my bones are vexed.\\!
    \end{verse} 
\end{document}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you for any guidance --

Comment: I'm not sure if you consider the contents of the `verse` environment to be a long line that automatically gets set as multiple lines or as individual lines which you have to specify.

Comment: I had been under the impression that "\\" ended a line within the verse environment. So in effect, an individual line is specified by a bunch of words that ends with "\\". Then the next line begins and goes on until the next "\\".

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but here is a patch that will probably be the solution that will be added to `memoir`. Note that it will require a modern LaTeX installation in order to use the paragraph hooks.

There are three main parts to this fix

- Use the verse+paragraph hook combo to add stuff automatically at the start of each verse line (which are actually paragraphs behind the scenes). Thank you to Ulrike Fischer who suggested it in chat.
- Replace the code used to place the line numbers
- Remove the line numbering part from the "new line" macro, and add it to the hook instead.

It solves a few extra issues with the numbering, fx the numbering used to require `\\` on all lines, even the last one. Now the last line is numbered even if `\\` is missing.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@vslnumleft{%
  \llap{%
    \llap{\vlvnumfont\getthelinenumber{poemline}{memfvsline}}%
    \hspace{\dimexpr\@totalleftmargin+\memRTLvrightskip}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*\@vslnumright{%
  \rlap{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr-\@totalleftmargin+\textwidth+\memRTLvrightskip}%
    {\vlvnumfont\getthelinenumber{poemline}{memfvsline}}%
  }%
}

\AddToHook{env/verse/begin}{\AddToHook{para/begin}[memoir/versenum]{\@vstypelinenum}} 
\AddToHook{env/verse/end}{\RemoveFromHook{para/begin}[memoir/versenum]}                 

\patchcmd{\@vscentercr}%
{\@vstypelinenum}%
{}% replacement
{}% ok
{\typeout{Patch for \string\@vstypelinenum\space failed}}% bad

\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    \linenumberfrequency{1}
    \verselinenumbersleft   
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{My soul also is sore troubled;}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]      
        O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger, neither chasten me in Thy wrath.\\
        Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; O Lord, heal me, for my bones are vexed.\\!
    \end{verse} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, more an admission of failure. I have tried many varieties of `verse` code but really no luck. I agree that the first line of a two line entry should be numbered instead of the second line. But ...

```
 % verseprob.tex  SE 609802

%! program = pdflatex
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
    
    \linenumberfrequency{1}
    \verselinenumbersleft   
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{My soul also is sore troubled;}

First verse.

    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]      
        O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger, neither chasten me in Thy wrath.\\
        Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; O Lord, heal me, for my bones are vexed.\\!
    \end{verse} 

Second verse.

    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]      
        O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger,\\!
         neither chasten me in Thy wrath.\\
\end{verse}

Third verse

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; O Lord, heal me, for my bones are vexed.\\!
    \end{verse} 

Fourth verse.

    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]      
        O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger,\\>
         neither chasten me in Thy wrath.%\\!
\end{verse}

Fifth verse

    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]      
        O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger, neither chasten me in Thy wrath.\\>[0pt]
        Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; O Lord, heal me, for my bones are vexed.\\!
    \end{verse} 

Sixth verses.

    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]      
        O LORD, rebuke me not in Thine anger,\\>
         neither chasten me in Thy wrath.%\\!
\end{verse}
%\setcounter{poemline}{2}
\vspace{-1.8\baselineskip}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth] \setcounter{poemline}{2}
%  \setcounter{vslineno}{2}
        Have mercy upon me, O Lord, for I am weak; \\>
        O Lord, heal me, for my bones are vexed.%\\!
    \end{verse} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have spent quite a lot of time looking at the `memoir` code but must confess that I no longer understand it; my memory is fading. Hopefully Lars Madsen (aka daleif) the `memoir` maintainer will be able to help.